# Firewall/routing rule in Centos for this setup

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall, routing

I have two ethernet interfaces, namely `eth0` and `eth1`.
I want to implement an advanced routing rule but I am totally new to firewall/routing rules in CentOS.

Here is what I am trying to do:

Both my interfaces are up and connected to internet. I want to be able to decide dynamically based on the type of traffic through which interface it should go out.

For example, if it is HTTP traffic, I want it to use `eth0` and if it is FTP etc traffic, I want it to use `eth1`, while different type of traffic could have the SAME destination IP address.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: A couple of questions: Is the traffic originating from the connected machine?  If not, are you using NAT?

Comment: @utopiabound, for now i want to test with traffic originating from same machine, however the ultimate goal is exactly in a NAT'd scenario which i wouuld implement on both of these interfaces (may be) not really sure though

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output traffic on different interfaces based on destination port](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/output-traffic-on-different-interfaces-based-on-destination-port)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Advanced Routing & Traffic Control HOWTO](http://lartc.org/howto/index.html) should have what you need.  Once you setup your networks, you'll want to write some rules that will mark packets to go over the alternate connection in iptables (see [Chapter 11 Netfilter & iproute - marking packets](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.netfilter.html)).