# iptables --set-mark - Route diferent ports through different interfaces

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, routing, route

Short story,
3 interfaces, eth0 (LAN), eth1(ADSL), eth2(4G).
eth0 -> eth1: Works
(ports 80, 443, 4070) eth0 -> eth2: Doesn't happen

## This is a graphical representation of the idea:

Port 80 & 443 via eth2
ant the rest via eth1
[image]

### Netscheme:

```
eth0: -ip 10.0.0.1 -net 10.0.0.0/8 -gw 10.0.0.1 (the servers own intf) 
eth1: -ip 192.168.1.74 -net 192.168.1.0/24 -gw 192.168.1.254 
eth2: -ip 192.168.1.91 -net 192.168.0.0/24 -gw 192.168.0.1
```

---

---

**This new script reroutes 22 and 4070 to the proper table, I think.

However, after getting to that table, it doesn't get rerouted to eth2.**

---

## This script works, except for 22 and 4070!

(Port 80 is un-commented and it works but via eth1 which is wrong.)

```
modprobe iptable_nat
modprobe ip_conntrack

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -F PREROUTING
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
# This next line restores any issues trying to connect to something
# if you get weird ACK packets when trying to connect (at least i did)!
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
ip route flush table main

iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -t mangle -p tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 1
###  iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -t mangle -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -t mangle -p tcp --dport 4070 -j MARK --set-mark 1

## Setup routes
# LAN
route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 dev eth0
# ADSL
route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth1
# 4G (Only accessible if marking packages with \x01
route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth2
# Default via ADSL
## -- Does the same as ip route below? route add default gw 192.168.1.254


echo "201 eth2.out" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

ip rule add fwmark 1 table eth2.out
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth2 table eth2.out
ip route add default via 192.168.1.254 dev eth1



## Setup forwards
# From 4G to LAN
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED,NEW -j ACCEPT
# From ADSL to LAN
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED,NEW -j ACCEPT
# From LAN to ADSL (Default route out)
# - Note: If marked packages is sent to ADSL they will be mangled and rerouted to 4G
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
```

## Old script:

---

```
  Ignore everything below unless you're interested in retracing my steps!!
```

---

I've created a router.sh script to setup my environment in case I do something bad.
I've got 3 ports which I want to send to a 4G connection and the rest via a landline ADSL connection.
To do this, I've instructed iptables to mangle packages on the default route and send them via my 4G interface if the --dport == 443 | 80 | 4070

However, this doesn't work; I'm still getting routed through my landline no matter what.

This is what my script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

## routing tables
# wireless = 4G via eth2
# adsl = adsl via eth1

modprobe iptable_nat
modprobe ip_conntrack

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -F FORWARD
iptables -t nat -F
ip route flush table main
ip route flush table wireless
ip route flush table adsl

## Setup routing tables
# ADSL
ip route add table adsl to 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1
# 4G
ip route add table wireless to 192.168.0.0 dev eth2
ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table wireless

## Setup routes
# LAN
route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 dev eth0
# ADSL
route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth1
# 4G (Only accessible if marking packages with \x01
route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth2
# Default via ADSL
route add default gw 192.168.1.254


## Forward ports into the LAN
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.3:80


## Lets mark all packets we want for 4G forward
# HTTPS
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 1
# HTTP
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 1
# Spotify
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 4070 -j MARK --set-mark 1

## Setup forwards
# From 4G to LAN
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED,NEW -j ACCEPT
# From ADSL to LAN
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# From LAN to ADSL (Default route out)
# - Note: If marked packages is sent to ADSL they will be mangled and rerouted to 4G
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG
#iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth2 --jump SNAT --to-source "192.168.1.74"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

I've also tried to add these 3 to the bottomg of the script:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to "192.168.0.91"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -p tcp --dport 443 -j SNAT --to "192.168.0.91"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -p tcp --dport 4070 -j SNAT --to "192.168.0.91"
```

Also tried without success:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

Last but not least, tried:

```
## Lets mark all packets we want for 4G forward
# HTTPS
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t mangle -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j MARK --set-mark 1
# HTTP
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t mangle -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j MARK --set-mark 1
# Spotify
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t mangle -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 4070 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

The routing works, I can browse the web, listen to music and what-not, but I'm doing it through the wrong interface.
I've Googled around for a long while now and found bits and pieces to understand what I'm doing and why I'm doing it. I could do traffic shaping via tc but if it's possible via marking packages in iptables it would help me a long way.

My guess is that I'm doing the order wrong on the different rules, mainly the **MASQUERADE** part? or if that should even be there?

Can someone explain how to **DNAT** port say, tcp:80 from an external interface (either one or BOTH protocols) to a internal 10.0.0.0 address space?

Outputs:

```
root@Netbridge:~# route -n Kernel IP routing table Destination    

Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface<br>
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1<br>
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eth0<br>
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2<br>
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

```
root@Netbridge:~# ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:7e:9e:4e  
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:7e:9e:58  
          inet addr:192.168.1.74  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:7e:9e:62  
          inet addr:192.168.0.91  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

Followed these instructions:
[output-traffic-on-different-interfaces-based-on-destination-por](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/output-traffic-on-different-interfaces-based-on-destination-port?rq=1)
[iptables-forward-specific-port-to-specific-nic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231279/iptables-forward-specific-port-to-specific-nic)

Among a few other related threads.

Comment: I'm sorry, but is there a reason to don't bind apache only to the `localhost` and to the address of `eth2` interface?

Comment: @JanMarek: There is no mention of apache here. And for your information, binding a socket on an `ethX`'s ip address will prevent hosts on the `ethX` lan to access the local server using `ethY`'s ip address, and will not prevent hosts from the `ethY` to access the server using `ethX`'s ip address. Remember that Linux uses a weak host model.

Comment: OK, there is possible more web servers, not only apache server... I though, that bind web server on the interface eth2 can be a simple solution. But I can be wrong, I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BatchyX already give some very good explanation about iptables and routing, so I will exercise my laziness and go directly to script.

It should NAT all traffic to port 80,443,22,4070 through 192.168.0.91. All the rest will NAT through 192.168.1.254.

I re-do my testing and end up following this [guide](http://linux-ip.net/html/adv-multi-internet.html). What is missing in that guide is the last 3 lines in my script. Which I found out from another port, but I lost track of that link.

It is a tested working script.

**Need Default Route**

One thing I did not put in the script is setting up the default route. It should be

```
route add default gw 192.168.1.254
```

When you do `route -n`, it should be the only default route (Dest:0.0.0.0)

```
0.0.0.0    192.168.1.254    0.0.0.0    UG    0    0    0    eth1
```

**fw-router.sh**

```
# Reset/Flush iptables
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

#Reset/Flush/Setup IP Route (table 4)
ip route flush table 4
ip route show table main | grep -Ev ^default | while read ROUTE ; do ip route add table 4 $ROUTE ; done
ip route add table 4 default via 192.168.0.1

#Mark Packet with matching D.Port
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22   -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 4
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80   -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 4
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443  -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 4
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 4070 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j MARK --set-mark 4

#SNAT Rules
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.74
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.0.91

#IP Route
ip rule add fwmark 4 table 4
ip route flush cache

#IP Stack
#This is the missing part from the guide
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
for f in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter ; do echo 0 > $f ; done
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush
```

**PS1:** In short, `MASQUERADE` does not work (in most case, and definitely in your case) for NAT with multiple external IPs that need some kind of load balancing or need DNAT to handle incoming traffic. You need `SNAT` for direction control.

**PS2:** Pure iptables is not sufficient.

Comment: First of all, cheers for going directly to script :) I'll try this tonight as i get back to the environment in which this will run at!

Comment: hmm, may need heavy revise. Let me know result.

Comment: Revised, should be working now.

Comment: Sweet, will get back to you in a short bit :D

Comment: I love you, so much headache and you solved it! Thank you!

Comment: And merry Christmas to you! (if you celebrate it ofc, some don't)

Comment: LOL, Thx! Yes, I enjoy X'mas!

Comment: Exactly worked! Although not clear why default gateway is required, it seems true that if default gateway not set for default table, all marked packet would not work as expected to matching dedicated tables.

Answer (score 6):

Note: I only have considered the first script, ignoring the old one.

- You don't need to modprobe netfilter modules by hand with current iptables. This is only necessary for custom connection trackers.
- Don't mix up `route` and `ip route`. This is pure evil. Just use `ip` everywhere and forget about `ifconfig` and `route`
- `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` is not reset across reboots. Appending the same entry over and over is not a good idea, you only need to do it once. Remember that `rt_tables` just define name aliases to numeric values, it does not change any configuration.
- Now for `iptables`:
  In your `FORWARD` chain, you drop packets coming from LAN to 4G. This is bad.  the `FORWARD` hook is used after routing is done. At this point, all policy routing is done, and it is already known whether the packet should be sent to 4G or ADSL. There is no rerouting done in `FORWARD` or after `FORWARD` (well, technically, rerouting can be done after `POSTROUTING` in severe cases, but back to the point).

Now for your routing: Remember that Ubuntu enables reverse path filtering by default. Reverse path filtering works as follow: When the kernel receives a packet (may it be forwarded or not) from an interface A, it will invert the source address and the destination address, and check if the resulting packet should be routed through interface A. If it isn't, the packet is dropped as a address spoofing attempt.

For packets received from `eth0`, this is not a problem. For packets received from `eth1`, this is also not a problem, because when reversing the source IP address and the destination IP address, the kernel will it the default route in table `main`. For packets received from `eth2`, which you do not mark, this is a problem, because the kernel will hit the default route in table `main`, and consider that these packets should have been received from `eth1`. The easiest solution is to disable reverse path filtering on eth1:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter=0
```

Comment: All great comments and yes, there are some faulty logic on my part, for instance appending to rt_tables each time and especially not clearing certain tables as well as i should but i'll get there :) I'll give everything a go and see if it works, if so, +50 to you and most importantly you've saved a mans behind from being chopped into bits and peaces! :)

Comment: Below script works but you sir deserve all the gratitude as well, you gave me a thing or two to think about and rp_filter=0 helped a long way! :D

Comment: @BatchyX very informative, up vote to you too.

Comment: @Torxed The post I saw mention rp_filter for ALL interface need to be disabled. I am not sure if it works other way.

Comment: @JohnSiu: You just need to disable rp filter on interfaces where it is problematic. In that case, it's eth1, because there is no route going to that interface when marks are not set. eth2 has no such problem, as the default route goes into that interface. For eth0, it is actually useful to keep rp filter enabled, otherwise, someone on the LAN could forge an IP packet with a source address being on the internet and a destination address on the LAN, and the router would happily accept it, and forward it back to ... eth0.