# Route outgoing traffic to different gateway based on port

Tags: networking, routing

I am trying to get around my Usenet download bandwidth restrictions based on IP.

I currently have two IPs from my ISP to double the download speed. So far I have it working and getting double speed from one server that has multiple access addresses, by using this command to get a second stream going with the first on eth0.
sudo route add -host xx.xx.xxx.20 gw 192.168.2.1 dev wlan0

My problem is another service I want to do the same only has one address but multiple port choices. So how can I send any data to a different gateway based on the port.

Default example.com:80 should use the 192.168.1.1 gateway on eth0 (which it does since this is the default gateway)
Whereas example.com:81 should use the 192.168.2.1 gateway on wlan0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output traffic on different interfaces based on destination port](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/output-traffic-on-different-interfaces-based-on-destination-port)

Comment: I had tried that before even posting my question. If it does work I don't know enough to modify it to my needs.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry you're not doing this from the gateway. So you need a similar marking but then set a different route based on this marking. See [iptables --set-mark - Route diferent ports through different interfaces](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58635/iptables-set-mark-route-diferent-ports-through-different-interfaces), but it's a bit messy, we should be able to write a clearer answer for your case. I'm retracting my close vote.

Comment: To be clear on my setup. I have my ISP modem/router in bridge mode and two separate routers plugged into it. Then I am wired into one router (good new Gigabit for my LAN transfers) and wireless into the other. The wireless is old and slow but enough to cover the 7-8 megabits I plan on putting through it. Not for any other traffic.
The server is running Linux.