# Ip route: Routing with two interfaces (only one connected to Internet)

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, networkmanager, wicd

I have this problem:
I have a laptop with WiFi and eth.

The WiFi is connected to the internet and has the following config:
`192.168.1.100` and `192.168.1.1` as gateway

The eth is connected in this way and it does not have access to internet:
`192.168.0.100` and `192.168.0.254` as gateway

How can I make that internet works correctly and when I go to `192.168.0.254` it connects to the subnet?

PS: I use NetworkManger, but in case I can use Wicd.
The OS is ArchLinux.

Comment: in network concept, YOU CANT TWO DEFAULT GW CUNCURRECNTLY....

Comment: Thats simple. You don't need a gateway on your `eth` interface. You are the gateway to the net you are member, talking on a very very simple way. You just need the wifi gateway, and you are good to go. If you take a look at your routes, you will have something like `192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.22  metric 9` that translates to - "To access all the /24 subnet, use ME(my ip address) as the source of this route"

Comment: You can definitely have two default gateways on a system [you just have to do policy-based routing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171482/always-forward-traffic-out-the-interface-it-originated-on) to specify which gateway gets selected when. This may or may not play well with `NetworkManager` you may have to try it to see.

Comment: If I'm understanding above you would specify the default gateway in your main routing table as being the internet gateway, but do the `ip route add table 2` and `ip rule` commands for the `192.168.0.254` address.

Comment: We may also need to know more about your network setup since if linux tries to send to a node that's on the same subnet as an interface, the routing table is usually already configured to send it out that interface. The only time you should run into routing issues is when you have multiple local subnets and need to send traffic through a local gateway.

Comment: Ok, maybe I've found a solution (I need to test it further though...)  
Just check in the IPv4 tab the option "Use this connection only for resources on its network".  
In this way NetworkManager doesn't create an additional default gw and internet works correctly... :P