# How can I set the "default route" when an interface has multiple IPs?

Tags: ip, routing, aws

I've followed this guide for [Multiple IP addresses on Amazon EC2](http://engineering.silk.co/post/31923247961/multiple-ip-addresses-on-amazon-ec2) and have gone with the second method listed of adding two IP addresses to a single interface. This was done by adding two private IPs to the adapter and then associating an elastic IP with each of the private addresses.

When I run a command like `curl` it uses the primary IP address and I would like to know how to change it to use the other IP address by default. Here is the setup:

#### Public (elastic) IPs

```
54.140.250.140
54.81.231.80
```

#### Private IPs

```
172.30.0.50
172.30.0.122
```

After adding the elastic and private IPs I do this:

```
ip addr add dev eth0 172.30.0.122/24
```

To confirm it's working I can do:

```
curl icanhazip.com
54.81.231.80

curl --interface 172.30.0.50 icanhazip.com
54.81.231.80

curl --interface 172.30.0.122 icanhazip.com
54.140.250.140
```

As you can see the default route is done via the original / primary IP.

Here is the data from running `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:34:56:78:90:ab
          inet addr:172.30.0.50  Bcast:172.30.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: aabb::cccc:dddd:eeee:ffff/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:713 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:631 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:63726 (63.7 KB)  TX bytes:827217 (827.2 KB)

lo        .... omitted ....
```

And this is what I get from running `route`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.30.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.30.0.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I tried changing the 'default' route with a script like this. I used `screen` so that the script would continue after I get disconnected (guessing that the first line causes that):

```
/sbin/route del default
/sbin/route add default via 172.30.0.122 dev eth0 tab 1
```

I also tried without the `tab 1` but still had no luck.

#### How can I set what outgoing IP is used 'by default' ?

I would also like to know if it is possible to specify that only traffic to a certain range of IPs use the secondary address as the default address.

Comment: Why not create separate subnet for second IP on the device and then add appropriate route for that subnet?

Comment: If all you're looking to do is change the default gateway you can use `ip route change default via <gateway-ip>` Deleting your gateway probably is what's causing the problems if you're not on the same subnet.

Comment: @Miline - I could also add a second interface. That article has some good details about that method, too. I just thought there should be a simpler solution.

Comment: For your second question: You would set up an alternate routing table and [use ip rule](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171482/always-forward-traffic-out-the-interface-it-originated-on) to say that all traffic coming from the secondary IP will use the gateway you're wanting.

Comment: @Bratchley - just attempted `ip route change default via 172.30.0.122` and have lost the connection / server is no longer responding. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure the gateway IP is correct? Meaning both that it's the gateway and traffic will return to your system's IP address? Does the `.122` gateway's network maybe blocked all unrecognized traffic? Where is the gateway IP address coming from?

Comment: If you connect on console and do a `ip route` you should see it made the change to the default gateway (otherwise it would've error'd changing nothing). Meaning there's probably an issue with using that IP for the gateway.

Comment: Actually I just saw your mistake. You're using the interface's IP address as the gateway. You need to specify the router's IP address as the gateway IP. Right now you're telling linux to forward packets to itself. Since it's a `/24` subnet mask, your default gateway probably isn't changing on this one. You're just using two different IP's on the same subnet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ip route replace default via 172.30.0.1 src 172.30.0.122
```