# Route only ssh traffic through VPN

Tags: ssh, routing, vpn, remote-management

Is it possible to route a computer's SSH service through a VPN connection but allow ALL other data to exit through the WAN address? What sort of iptables magic needs to be done to accomplish this?

SSH data → goes through VPN
ALL other data → goes through default route

Answer (score 3):

My answer is related to the [answer of related, but more complicate question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21093/15241) and not tested.

You need the `iproute2` package installed.

Add to `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` the line

```
200 vpn-route
```

and then write a script that you call after VPN is initialized:

```
# set default gateway of vpn-route
ip route add default via $VPNGATEWAY dev $VPNINTERFACE table vpn-route
# use this for marked packages
ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table vpn-route
# mark outgoing ssh packages
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -o $WANINTERFACE -p tcp --dport 22 -j MARK --set-mark 1
# rewrite source address
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $VPNINTERFACE -j MASQUERADE
```

Of course, you need to replace the `$...` variables with their actual values.

PS: If your IP on the WAN-interface is fix, you can replace the last line with
    `iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o $WANINTERFACE -p tcp --dport 22 -j SNAT --to $WANIP`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to a server using ssh through VPN since your company requires a VPN connection to access the server, there is another way to bypass the VPN. 
First, you need to connect to your server using VPN. 
Then, start [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to open a reverse ssh (is this the correct term?)

```
ngrok tcp 22
```

This will give you an address and a port. It usually looks like this: `0.tcp.eu.ngrok.io:12345`.
Now, you can stop your VPN and ssh to your server using the above address and port.

```
ssh yourname@0.tcp.eu.ngrok.io -p 12345
```