# Route socks proxy traffic through wireless client

Tags: ssh, routing, proxy

I have  a router with two Internet WANs: DSL (vlan1) and wireless client (eth1). They are both in default route: vlan is the first and eth1 is the second (I am using `ip route add default scope global nexthop via …`).

I want to use eth1 Internet from my laptop using socks proxy. I tried to use srelay socks server with `–J eth1` option on the router but it didn’t  work (page loads forever) although it works through DSL if I use `–J vlan1`. I also tried to use `ssh` as a socks server and mark packets with iptables to route them to eth1 using ip rule:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -o vlan1 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

After this command every program on the router starts using eth1 but I need that only the socks server uses eth1.
Is it possible to mark only socks server packets? Now I have to use the second router for this purpose. I run socks server on it and add ip rule for its IP on the first router.

I already tried [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/output-traffic-on-different-interfaces-based-on-destination-port) and it didn’t work. It’s not "duplicate" because I need this for proxy server on router. The problem is that I can’t mark packets based on port number because proxy server doesn’t keep this mark while proxyfing.