# Route HTTP traffic thorugh different interface

Tags: iptables, routing, interface

I have my normal `eth0` interface and an setup `ppp0` interface, the problem I have is that I want to exclusively route all HTTP/HTTPS traffic through the `ppp0` interface and everything else through the default `eth0`. I tried adding a route rule `route add default dev ppp0` but of course this will route everything through the `ppp0` interface, I might need iptables but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that http traffic will be limited to port 80 you could use the [solution here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21093/53092)

Sorry for the poor quality of my answer. Phone is not easy to master.