# iptables selectable tunnel

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, route

I have this configuration script:

### I OPENVPN TUNNELS

```
openvpn --config serverx.ovpn  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
openvpn --config servery.ovpn  > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

TEST ON MY SCRIPT which outputs the connection address

```
route add 69.195.103.232/32 dev tun0
curl http://checkmyproxy.xx/checkproxy.php
route delete 69.195.103.232
```

I GET THE CORRECT SERVERX IP

### I PREPARE IPTABLES

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -X
```

### I EDIT RT_TABLES

```
nano /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

I ADD IN RT_TABLES

```
100 tunnel0
101 tunnel1
```

THEN

```
ip route add default dev tun0 table tunnel0
ip route add default dev tun1 table tunnel1
ip rule add from all fwmark 0x100 table tunnel0
ip rule add from all fwmark 0x101 table tunnel1
ip route flush cache
ip rule show
```

### ALL FINE, I get the following results

IFCONFIG

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.10  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ETC ETC
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        ETC ETC
tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.120.1.6  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.120.1.5
        ETC ETC, IP CLASS CAN VARY
tun1: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.199.1.6  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.199.1.5
        ETC ETC, IP CLASS CAN VARY
```

ROUTES

```
default         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.151.1.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.199.1.5      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

IP RULE SHOW

```
0:  from all lookup local 
32764:  from all fwmark 0x100 lookup tunnel0 
32765:  from all fwmark 0x101 lookup tunnel1 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

### I MARK PACKETS to associate to the right route / interface

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --sport 10000 -j MARK --set-mark 100
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p tcp --sport 10001 -j MARK --set-mark 101
iptables-save
```

### AND THE QUESTION IS

How can I obtain to return server x IP and server y IP for the first and for the second request, using the following commands?

```
 curl http://checkmyproxy.xx:10000/checkproxy.php
 curl http://checkmyproxy.xx:10001/checkproxy.php
```

The final port is always 80, so 10000 and 10001 should be translated as 80.
This other translates correctly, but I get the eth0 real address (no tunneling), so it bypassess the mangle mark

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 10000 -j DNAT --to :80
iptables-save
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved and documented it here:
http://aftermanict.blogspot.it/2015/11/bash-iptables-iproute2-and-multiple.html