# iptables NAT multiple devices with same IP address

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi, nat, iproute

I have a challenging situation where I have 5 devices which act as wireless access points. I need to be able to access TCP `8080` on each device from a central device. All wireless devices have a `192.168.122.1` address and dish out a DHCP address over wireless. I have a Pi connected via 5 wireless cards (on a powered hub) as so....

[image]

Ideally I want to connect to `eth0` on the Pi nic on ports `8081,8082` etc and be NAT'd to each of the different devices on port `8080`. I looked into namespaces but my wireless cards don't support it so I need to find a solution with `ip route / iptables`. Been thrashing around for a few days and haven't found a good example to work from. Some help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this Q&A, you need to do something like this - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/output-traffic-on-different-interfaces-based-on-destination-port.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an iptables expert by any means but this is what finally worked with help from this [article](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/output-traffic-on-different-interfaces-based-on-destination-port) suggested above from [Arushix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/290485/arushix).

```
#!/bin/bash

#flush routes
ip route flush 192.168.122.0/24
ip route flush 192.168.122.1
ip route flush default via 192.168.122.1

#flush iptables
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -F
iptables -X

#NAT'd packet responses sent back to the eth0 ip
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.2.38
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE

#Add a separate routing table and firewall mark for each incoming port  
ip rule add fwmark 4 table 4

#mark the packets
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8084 -j MARK --set-mark 4

#route through the appropriate interface    
ip route add 192.168.122.0/24 dev wlan4 table 4

#packets to 8084 nat'd to device 8080
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8084 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.1:8080

#turn off spoofing protection
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=0

#do it for all the interfaces 
ip rule add fwmark 3 table 3
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8083 -j MARK --set-mark 3
ip route add 192.168.122.0/24 dev wlan3 table 3
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8083 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.1:8080  

ip rule add fwmark 2 table 2
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8082 -j MARK --set-mark 2
ip route add 192.168.122.0/24 dev wlan2 table 2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8082 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.1:8080

ip rule add fwmark 1 table 1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8081 -j MARK --set-mark 1
ip route add 192.168.122.0/24 dev wlan1 table 1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8081 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.1:8080
```