# Route specific layer 2 traffic output to another interface

Tags: output, route, interface

Supposing I have 1 interface (wlan0) and 1 virtual interface (wlan0:0).

What I want is to route specific layer 2 traffic (arp request only for example) from wlan0 to wlan0:0

My problem is very similar to the following question, but for layer 2:
[Only allow certain outbound traffic on certain interfaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12085/only-allow-certain-outbound-traffic-on-certain-interfaces)

Comment: you want to filter packet based on layer 2 protocols ?

Comment: yes, redirect outgoing layer 2 traffic from wlan0 to wlan0:0. If possible, only specific layer 2 traffic (like just ARP for example).

Comment: what do you mean 'redirect'

Comment: you can match the arp request and send a arp replay with any mac you want, but redirect i can't see the point of that

Comment: Simulating a VPN is a nice example of that. ARP request is forwarded into the VPN. I want to do a similar thing, excepted that I don't want to redirect all traffic but only ARP for example, to a virtual interface.